# DTS package not copying all files from folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a package that I developed in SQL 2008 R2 which copies files from a location based on the date since the file names have a date appended to them. The package runs fine when run from within BIDS and returns the requested files but when this is automated using task scheduler the package does not copy all the files. My environmment is SSIS 2008 R2 and the reason I trigger the package from a batch file is because the box on which the package is running has no database server but only client tools. How can I make sure that my package returns all the requested files irrespective of how the package is triggered.

Thanks in advance